# Get data and send mail script

Tags: python, performance, mongodb

I wrote a script using Python that gets data from several sources (news sites, Twitter, Yahoo), puts it into a dict and then formats it as a string to be sent through email.

I wonder if there is possibility to write the code more neatly in a shorter way. Maybe I'm doing some steps that are a bit unnecessary and maybe faster and I could do it differently, but not sure how.

```
import json
import urllib.request
from twitter import Twitter, OAuth, TwitterHTTPError, TwitterStream 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import datetime
from pymongo import MongoClient 
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import smtplib
import os
#from config import *

now = datetime.datetime.now()
api_news= os.environ["api_news"]

#twitter setup
ACCESS_TOKEN = os.environ["ACCESS_TOKEN"]
ACCESS_SECRET = os.environ["ACCESS_SECRET"]
CONSUMER_KEY = os.environ["CONSUMER_KEY"]
CONSUMER_SECRET = os.environ["CONSUMER_SECRET"]
oauth = OAuth(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
twitter = Twitter(auth=oauth)

#polish
pol_trends = twitter.trends.place(_id = 23424923)
twittrendlistPL=[]
for i in pol_trends[0]['trends']:
    twittrendlistPL.append(i['name'])
strPLT="<br>".join(str(x) for x in twittrendlistPL[0:15])

#global trends
globaltrends=twitter.trends.place(_id = 1)
twittrendlist=[]
for i in globaltrends[0]['trends']:
    twittrendlist.append(i['name'])    
def isEnglish(s):
    try:
        s.encode(encoding='utf-8').decode('ascii')
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        return False
    else:
        return True    
G=[i for i in twittrendlist if isEnglish(i)]
strGT="<br>".join(str(x) for x in G[0:15])

#us headlines
url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?'
       'country=us&'+api_news)
response = requests.get(url)
listus=[]
for i in range(len(response.json()['articles'])):
    listus.append(response.json()['articles'][i]['title'])
    listus.append(response.json()['articles'][i]['url'])    
strNUS="<br>".join(str(x) for x in listus[0:10])


#uk headlines
url = ('https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?country=gb&'+api_news)
response = requests.get(url)
listGB=[]
for i in range(len(response.json()['articles'])):
    listGB.append(response.json()['articles'][i]['title'])
    listGB.append(response.json()['articles'][i]['url'])
strGB="<br>".join(str(x) for x in listGB[0:10])


#google news(global) headlines
url = ("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=google-news&"+api_news)
response = requests.get(url)
listg=[]
for i in range(len(response.json()['articles'])):
    listg.append(response.json()['articles'][i]['title'])
    listg.append(response.json()['articles'][i]['url'])
strg="<br>".join(str(x) for x in listg[0:10])


#most popular from technology
url = ("https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?category=technology&country=us&sortBy=popularity&"+api_news)

response = requests.get(url)
listt=[]
for i in range(len(response.json()['articles'])):
    listt.append(response.json()['articles'][i]['title'])
    listt.append(response.json()['articles'][i]['url'])
strt="<br>".join(str(x) for x in listt[0:10])

#yahoo trending charts
page = requests.get("https://finance.yahoo.com/trending-tickers/")
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
base=soup.findAll('td', {'class':'data-col1 Ta(start) Pstart(10px) Miw(180px)'})
yhoo=[]
for i in base:
    yhoo.append(i.get_text())
strYHOO='<br>'.join(str(x) for x in yhoo[0:15])

#crypto trends to find
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/") as url:
    cmc = json.loads(url.read().decode())
names=[]
change=[]
for i in cmc['data']:
    names.append(cmc['data'][i]['symbol'])
    change.append(cmc['data'][i]['quotes']['USD']['percent_change_24h'])
change, names = zip(*sorted(zip(change, names)))
cmcstr='<br>'.join([str(a) + ': '+ str(b) + '%' for a,b in zip(names[-5:],change[-5:])])

#create a dict to upload for db
maind={
    "Global Twitter trends": strGT,
    "Polish Twitter trends" : strPLT,
    "Top US headlines": strNUS,
    "Top UK headlines": strGB,
    "Top Google News headlines": strg,
    "Top tech headlines": strt,
    "Trending yahoo stocks": strYHOO,
    "CMC trending": cmcstr,
    "Date": str(datetime.date.today())
}

#create and connect to mongo database
mongo=os.environ["mongodb"]
try: 
    #local test
    #conn = MongoClient()
    #production
    conn = MongoClient(mongo)
    print("Connected successfully!!!") 
except:   
    print("Could not connect to MongoDB") 

#Create/conn database 
db = conn.database 

# Created or Switched to collection names: trends
collection = db.trends

# Insert Data 
rec_id1 = collection.insert_one(maind) 
print("Data inserted with record ids",rec_id1) 

mpass=os.environ["mpass"]

record = collection.find_one({'Date': str(datetime.date.today())}) #create record that is from today
#convert all from database so that its easier to put into mail
gtt=record["Global Twitter trends"]
ptt=record["Polish Twitter trends"]
tus=record["Top US headlines"]
tuk=record["Top UK headlines"]
tgn=record["Top Google News headlines"]
tech=record["Top tech headlines"]
cmc=record["CMC trending"]
yahoo=record["Trending yahoo stocks"]
date=record["Date"]

#crate function to send mail
def send_email(date, *args):
    #login data
    from_email="" #sending mail
    from_password=mpass
    to_email="" #recipient

    subject="Daily trends {0}".format(date)
    message="Today's dose of news and trends starting with global twitter trends:<br> <strong>{0}</strong>. <br> <br> Polish twitter:<br> <strong>{1}</strong> <br> <br> Top us headlines:<br> <strong>{2}</strong> <br> <br> Top uk headlines:<br> <strong>{3}</strong> <br> <br> Top news headlines:<br> <strong>{4}</strong> <br> <br> Tech news:<br> <strong>{5}</strong> <br> <br> CMC trending:<br> <strong>{6}</strong> <br> <br> Yahoo trending:<br> <strong>{7}</strong> <br>".format(*args)
    msg=MIMEText(message, 'html') #msg setup
    msg['Subject']=subject
    msg['To']=to_email
    msg['From']=from_email
    gmail=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587) #mail setup
    gmail.ehlo()
    gmail.starttls()
    gmail.login(from_email, from_password)
    gmail.send_message(msg)

send_email(date, gtt, ptt, tus, tuk, tgn, tech, cmc, yahoo)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Now isn't now

You call `now` at the top of the program. First of all, it's never used, so it should be deleted. Even if it were used, this call should be moved next to the usage so that any delay between program start and the usage of this variable won't introduce error.

## Use what Python gives you

In this case, `os.environ["api_news"]` is more easily expressed as:

```
from os import getenv
# ...
api_news = getenv('api_news')
```

## Configuration

This isn't Python-specific, but for the kind of configuration you're pulling from the environment (access token, secret, etc.), the environment isn't really an appropriate place to keep it. Keep it in a permissions-protected file, perhaps JSON for ease of use.

## Make some functions

Resist the urge to dump all of your code into global scope. Make a `main` method and a handful of subroutines. This makes the stack trace meaningful if something goes wrong, and helps with maintainability.

## Use snake case

Python promotes `is_english` instead of `isEnglish`, in general.

## Use requests features

You're using requests, which buys you a lot of power. Strip the query params off of your url and pass them into `get` as a dictionary on the `params` kwarg.

## Only call json() once

You call `json()` a bunch of times on the response. Instead, you should probably save a temporary variable:

```
articles = response.json()['articles']
```

and work with that.

## Check for failure

Call `response.raise_for_status()`.

## Form strg as a text stream

Rather than populating `listg` in a loop and then `join`ing it to `strg`, you should make `strg` a `StringIO` and write it out that way, so that you don't need to hold onto a list object at all.

## Early-bail out of your loops

You're iterating over all of your content in several places but then only using the first ten items. Instead, slice the content before iterating. Also, don't use an index; iterate through the list itself. In other words:

```
for article in articles[:10]:
```

## Use f-strings

This:

```
str(a) + ': '+ str(b) + '%'
```

can be expressed as

```
f'{a}: {b}%'
```

## Don't except

There are a few problems with your bare `except:`. First of all, it's catching things you won't expect to catch, like a user's Ctrl+C. At the least, you should be doing `except Exception:`. Also, when you fail, you don't do anything useful. You should probably print the exception along with your failure message and re-raise rather than continuing on with your database code.